# Vue.js - appending a slot to another component

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I am trying to build a generic dropdown/popover/tooltip system in Vue.js.

The idea is to be able to open nested popover-esque elements, and manage their z layering, focus, re-focus on a child popover closing, etc. The underlying element positioning code may be the likes of Tether or Popper.

The API I want to have is this:

```
<div id="app">
    <div class="page">
        <tooltip>
            <button>Hover this</button>
            <div>Contents of tooltip</div>
        </tooltip>
    </div>
    <popover-container/>
</div>
```

The end result DOM I want to have is:

```
<div id="app">
    <div class="page">
        <button>Hover this</button>
    </div>
    <div class="popover-container">
        <div>Contents of tooltip</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It is imperative that the `<tooltip/>` component does **not** wrap the `<button/>` element in any additional DOM.

I have tried a number of approaches, none of which work, or at least not how I want them to.

**1. Slots**
I tried using slots for the `<tooltip/>` component. This creates a number of problems.
First, the tooltip content is appended right after the button.
Second, since you can't have multiple root nodes in a template, I had to wrap the `<button/>` and tooltip content in another element, which is a no-no.

I have tried the likes of `vue-popper-js`, which appends the tooltip content to the body, but it only happens in `$nextTick`, which means the template has to render with the wrapper span regardless.

**2. Virtual DOM**
I tried using Vue's `render` function. While I could render just the button, and using a standalone `Vue()` bus to send instructions to the `<popover-container/>` component to render the tooltip content, it is unable to update its content whenever the DOM is supposed to change.

Plus, there doesn't seem to be a documented way to clone `VNode`s, and since they are readonly, I cannot add event handlers. I hammered this together, but it's silly and wouldn't work the second my `<button/>` was a little more complex:

```
render: function (createElement) {
    let slotContent = this.$slots.default[0].componentOptions;
    return createElement(slotContent.Ctor, {
        props: slotContent.propsData,
        nativeOn: {
            mouseenter: this.onMouseEnter,
            ...slotContent.listeners
        }
    }, this.$slots.default);
}
```

I still use slots in this case, but updates to the tooltip content from the parent component aren't doing anything here. Every time I open the tooltip, it has the old content it was created with.

Anyway, how can I do this? Is it even possible in Vue?